# how to disable text correction programmatically in android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How can I disable the text correction programmatically in android using phonegap? User can disable it from settings, but I need disable it in my application using phonegap.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

These should work:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />

<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue in Chromium, which powers the webview for Android apps. According to the ticket the issue was fixed and marked as closed on October 8th, so it'll take some time for that to trickle down to the masses.

The ticket does mention a possible workaround by setting the input to `type="email"`. Not sure if that will help in your case.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: i tested it in android kit kat 4.4.4 and it works, but in others version of android like 4.4.2 didn't work. thank's in advance, and if you have another solution i will be very grateful.